# Defining tags and sequences with Boost.MPL in one shot

Tags: c++, boost, c++03, boost-mpl

I have a problem with Boost.MPL and I'm not sure how to approach it. Currently my code
looks like this:

```
struct Definition {
  typedef boost::mpl::int_<5> A;
  typedef boost::mpl::int_<3> B;
  typedef boost::mpl::int_<6> C;
  typedef boost::mpl::int_<1> D;
  // (...)

  typedef boost::mpl::vector<
    A
   ,B
   ,C
   ,D
    // (...)
  > Seq;
};
```

Here, the number `N` in `mpl::int_< N >` denotes some arbitrary decimal
number. Then some other code calculates the sum of these numbers up to
the type defined by "key", e.g. for `Definition::D`, the sum is 5 + 3 + 6
(A + B + C). This needs to be done at compile-time. That's why I use
`mpl::vector` and some appropriate meta-programming.

I don't like the current approach since it somehow violates the DRY rule.

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to provide such struct
definition without the need to repeat type names in the `mpl::vector` for
`Seq` type. In other words, I'd probably need a bunch of macros which
would allow me to write code like this:

```
struct Definition {
  FIELD(A, 5);
  FIELD(B, 3);
  FIELD(C, 6);
  FIELD(D, 1);
  // (...)
  GEN_SEQ() // only if really needed
};
```

And then `Definition::A` would still refer to `boost::mpl::int_<5>`, or
would at least allow me to access the `boost::mpl::int_<5>` somehow, and
`Definition::Seq` would give me the appropriate MPL sequence.

Of couse this is just my imagination. The code might look different, I'm
just looking for options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [metamonad](http://abel.web.elte.hu/mpllibs/metamonad/)? It has variable abstractions just like you seem to want:

```
#include <mpllibs/metamonad/eval_multi_let_c.hpp>
#include <mpllibs/metamonad/pair.hpp>
#include <mpllibs/metamonad/syntax.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal_to.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

#include <mpllibs/metamonad/metafunction.hpp>
#include <mpllibs/metamonad/lazy_metafunction.hpp>
#include <mpllibs/metamonad/returns.hpp>
#include <mpllibs/metamonad/name.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/times.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/divides.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/minus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal_to.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace mpllibs::metamonad::name;
    using boost::mpl::equal_to;
    using boost::mpl::plus;
    using boost::mpl::map;
    using boost::mpl::int_;

    using mpllibs::metamonad::eval_multi_let_c;
    using mpllibs::metamonad::syntax;
    using mpllibs::metamonad::pair;

    // test_evaluation_of_expression
    static_assert(
      equal_to<
        int_<14>,
        eval_multi_let_c<
          map<
              pair<a, syntax<int_<5>> >,
              pair<b, syntax<int_<3>> >,
              pair<c, syntax<int_<6>> >
          >,
          plus<a, b, c> >::type
      >::value, "Yay, maths still work"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to do everything programmatically, you need to have the names of your fields something that is accessible - which if you just name them `A`, `B`, ... isn't really. You could try to make your sequence incorporate both:

```
using namespace boost::mpl; // so I don't have to keep typing it

typedef map<
    pair<char_<'A'>, int_<5>>,
    pair<char_<'B'>, int_<3>>,
    pair<char_<'C'>, int_<6>>,
    ...
> Seq;
```

That way, for summing up to `'D'`, you would have:

```
template <char C>
struct sum_up_to {
    typedef typename boost::mpl::copy_if<Seq, 
        less_than<C>,
        boost::mpl::back_inserter< boost::mpl::vector<> >
        >::type NewSeq;

    typedef typename boost::mpl::accumulate<NewSeq, 
        boost::mpl::int_<0>,
        addNext>::type type;

    static const int value = type::value;
};
```

Where I leave the implementation of `less_than<C>` and `addNext` up to you. But this way you can just have `sum_up_to<'D'>::value == 14`.